# Recessed light is lighting dim and other stopped working

Tags: recessed-lighting

I have four recessed lights controlled by one switch and one recessed controlled by another switch , all of the sudden the two lights stopped working out of four and the single recessed light started lighting very Dim. After couple of days one light started working from out of two failed lights but it is not bright as before and single recessed light still lighting Dim. Not sure whats wrong. Please assist how to troubleshoot the issue and let me know if you need any additional details. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: What make and model are these recessed fixtures, and are you using incandescent, CFL, or LED bulbs in them?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thank you for the reply , i am really not sure about all the specifications, recently moved into this house and this is the first time running  into this situation, took the pictures of the light and attached. Don't find any big can for the light, just saw only small cup and wire ran through the cup and atached to light. Please let me know if you need more details,appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: This is what i found on online [https://www.build.com/sea-gull-lighting-14540s/s1679424?uid=3969213]